# Img src path from wp-admin

Tags: images, wp-admin, paths

Hi guys I have a quick question:

My path which I used for images in the php-files locally was something like this:

```
src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>/icons/cv_icon.png"
```

But from the wp-admin this doesnt work and I do have to for example:

```
src="wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/icons/about_icon.png"
```

First, why is that? Because i defined the THEME_IMG_PATH in function.php? But then why dont for example

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.jpg
```

or

`<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.jpg`

work? And, is the wp-content/... way the right way to do it, or should you do it in another way . in a way of good practice? It works but maybe its "wrong" to hardcode it like that.

This img shows that witt using php the php is not treated as code but the src url and another link/imageone showing as it should with a relative path.
[image]
Thanks

Solution: look further down on example for shortcoding, editing your functions and then calling this shortcode from wp-admin.

Comment: How are you defining `THEME_IMG_PATH ` ?

Comment: Like this:
`if( !defined(THEME_IMG_PATH)){
   define( 'THEME_IMG_PATH', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images' );
  }`
And the path is /images/icons/cv_icon.png.
Maybe it hasnt been set yet - that functions load after this somehow?

Comment: Add a trailing slash before all, `src="/<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>/icons/cv_icon.png"`?

Comment: @SamuelElh No, sadly not.

Comment: But also, the big question of course is - is it better to do this for some developing reasons in some other way than the whole `src="wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/icons/about_icon.png"` or just stick with it since its working

Comment: What is the URL in the src attribute in wp-admin ? `get_template_directory_uri()` should be a full URL including `http://` at the front.

Comment: @BenCasey Not sure what you mean exactly but Ive fiddles with http:// before the different ways and im not getting any result.
I guess from wp-admin im not directed to the same level as im from the .phpfiles somehow?

Comment: Im asking what is the URL that is not working for the image in wp-admin. The function `get_template_directory_uri()` should generate a full URL, not a relative one (like `/wp-content/themes/something/images/image.jpg`)

Comment: oh, its the one I mentioned earlier: 
`<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.jpg`

If i inspect my page I can see that a link with `src="wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/icons/about_icon.png"` reads http:/www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/icons/about.png and a image with `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/icons/about.png`
reads http:/www.mysite.com/<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/icons/about.png

Comment: Now I found out one thing, look at this picture and you see that with the get_template way the whole img settings like widht and height is showing as a link whereas the link with the relative path is showing as it should
Looks like the src isnt closed properly, but it is.

Comment: The editor doesnt allow php? It feels like its not treating it as php code.

Comment: The editor does allow PHP, although the editor shouldn't even exist IMO. Anyhow, can you show us the whole functions.php in a pastebin or something? I feel like you're trying to use PHP in a string making it unable to parse it as PHP.

Comment: Use a shortcode, @emcolsson, don't put PHP code into the editor. 1. In your child theme's functions file, add: `add_shortcode('get_template_directory_uri', 'get_template_directory_uri');`. 2. Now you can use `[get_template_directory_uri]/images/icons/about_icon.png`.

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow
Hi! Well its kinda long and Im only glad if you have constructive critizism against it and how I should use it. I think you can use this link to see it in full: [https://paste.ofcode.org/qvpAqpLmZV8z8Zu4ads3in]
Also I want to say that the define works in a .php file but not in wp-admin

Comment: @SamuelElh The shortcode worked out great!

Answer (score -1):

Best to use a images folder in your child theme and output like this:

```
$output = sprintf( '<img class="your-class" src="%s" alt="%s" />', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/image.jpg', get_the_title( $post->ID ) );
echo $output;
```

Comment: How would adding a child theme help? Even if there was no child theme, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() would still work. It would just select the active theme.

Comment: Always use a child theme or a custom functions plugin.

Comment: That depends. You're assuming this is a pre-developed theme. If it was, yes, use a child theme. If bespoke then no.